# How to set processing time event between SelectedIndexChanged and Normal Panel Update events?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i'm a vb.net developer and i'm facing with asp.net, so I'm a beginner with asp. I've triggered an event to `SelectedIndexChanged` of a list box; event is like that:

```
Protected Sub cmb_year_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_year.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

My problem is that pass about 4 seconds between my manual index change and the real panel update. I've set `UpdateMode` of panel `Conditional`.
Server runs locally and I'm using default developing environment (IIS express).

There is something that I don't understand about asp.net dynamics?

Comment: Please post the aspx markup too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use update panel with triggers.

Sample aspx mark up:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmb_year_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Sample code behind:

```
Protected Sub cmb_year_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_year.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, now I'm understanding. Your method is the same to put listbox inside UpdatePanel (leaving UpdateMode=Always) end put `Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red` in page load event?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the same. Thanks for your help!